# Use MongoDB field value as variable

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to take a field from a Mongo record and store it's value in a variable. The query below is returning the correct record but it's also returning the entire object. How do I pull the value of the 'sid' field?

Here is my schema:

```
var SessionsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      session: {
      sid: String,
      dataloop: {
          timeStamp: Date,
          sensorValues:{
              value: Number,
              index: Number
          }
      }
    }
});
```

Here is the query & function i'm using to store the value:

```
Sessions.find().sort({ 'sid' : -1 }).limit(1).exec(function(err, post) {
  if(post == null){
        lastSession = post.sid;
        sessionID = 1;
   }else {
        lastSession = post.sid;
        sessionID = lastSession++;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns an array, not an object,  you need to access `post` as an array. Use `post[0]` instead of `post`

Also, `post[0].sid` will be defined, you need to use it as `post[0].session.sid`.

```
Sessions.find().sort({ 'sid' : -1 }).limit(1).exec(function(err, post) { 
    if(post.length===0){ 
         lastSession = post[0].session.sid;  
         sessionID = 1; 
    }else { 
         lastSession = post[0].session.sid; 
        sessionID = lastSession++; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: The query only returns the first record in the collection, it's supposed to check the SID fields across the entire collection and then return a the highest.

Comment: This does work. I needed to specify the field location in the embedded document.